# Import module from file does not work

Tags: python

I am running a jupyter-notebook file (file.ipynb) and trying to import a module "eval_numerical_gradient" from python file "gradient_check" in folder "utils". However, the following code does not work.

```
from utils.gradient_check import eval_numerical_gradient
```

Then I try this code, which works:

```
import sys
sys.path.append("/Users/W/dlp/src/03/utils")
import gradient_check
from gradient_check import eval_numerical_gradient
```

My question is what is the difference of the two ways above, and is it possible to let the first code work out?

Comment: The second doesn't depend on `utils` being a package. It also works if there's something else called "utils".

Comment: Thanks! I guess the first does not regard the utils as a folder and that is the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just because you have it under folder `utils` does not make `utils` a package. You need an `__init__.py` file under folder `utils` if you want to define it as a `module`.

`__init__.py`: (place this under utils folder)

```
from .gradient_check import eval_numerical_gradient
```

`file.ipynb`:

```
import sys
sys.path.append("/Users/w/dlp/src/03")
from utils import eval_numerical_gradient
```

Comment: You no longer need `__init__.py` in Python 3 (which the questioner may or may not be using).

Comment: @DavisHerring your first comment isn't right. Splitting a package over several different folders (or a namespace package) is a distinct concept from an import package. Not an upgrade to get rid of `__init__.py`.

Comment: @DavisHerring With namespace packages (that is without `__init__.py`) you can have modules in sub-folders by the same name, in several different folders, and they still get found under that common sub-folder name, as if the modules were together.

Comment: @progmatico: I’m not sure what you’re getting at—because of the trivial case of a namespace package that federates only one directory, you don’t _need_ `__init__.py` (unless you want to define non-module members in it, of course), which is all I meant.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Unfortunately it still does not work. The first gives the message: **ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'utils.gradient_check'**. After having the `__init__.py`, it gives the message: **ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'gradient_check'**.

Comment: @Wenting.W I edited my answer. can you try this one and let me know how it went?

Comment: @AliYılmaz Hi Ali, thank you so much! It finally works now! That helps a lot.

Comment: @DavisHerring I am sorry that I didn't state the idea properly. Your comment is not literally wrong. It is right actually, but OP should be using `__init__.py` in their packages, unless he is trying on purpose to achieve what PEP420 allows (from abstract: Namespace packages are a mechanism for splitting a single Python package across multiple directories on disk.) . In the general case you want (regular) packages to be self-contained. `__init__.py` allows for initialization code and for name management (management of the exported names) if you need. But removing `__init__.py` brings ambiguity.

Comment: The imports will depend on `sys.path` that can be manipulated in many ways. It will also depend on other package installations. If one with the same name appears first in the path it will take precedence.over the loocal one.

Comment: So recommending it for general use is what I meant by wrong, not that it doesn't work. Maybe wrong is too strong, but not the best advice for the usual case, unless you really need it and you know what you are doing.

Comment: @progmatico: It’s fine to recommend `__init__.py`—I use it extensively myself.  But in the context of this question—“Why doesn’t this `import` work?”—the statement that “You need an `__init__.py`” may or may not be true, based on the unknown language version.  That was the sole import of the caution I offered.

Comment: That's ok, I understand you better now, I really focused in the comment itself, without considering it as an answer warning. And I was thinking of newbies that could read it. But I think our comments are now pretty clear for newbies.